# Git: "mixed" submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm aware of git submodules which dwell each in its own separate directory.

1. But is there such thing as "mixed" submodules whose content is "merged" together?

For instance:

- Submodule1 (path ./), consist of files `a.txt`, `b.txt` and directory `C` with the file `1.txt`
- Submodule2 (path ./), consist of files `x.txt`, `y.txt` and directory `C` with the file `2.txt`
- Resulting "mixed" repo of both submodules: files `a.txt`, `b.txt`, `x.txt`, `y.txt` and directory `C` with the files `1.txt`, `2.txt`

2. If it is not implemented in git - is there a workaround to achieve this?

Comment: Can you explain in more details what you intend to do with the "combined checkout" result ?

Comment: e.g : if your need is to "checkout the combination of these two directories on disk", yes, you can do it. If your need is to "version some franken-repo which would be the combination of the two histories of the submodules", I would suggest to not follow that path, and explain what you need to version instead.

Comment: Both submodules - independent libraries (collection of books as plain text files), which have same structure (directories = book categories). I want to present the combined git repository as full collection of books, while both projects evolve independently and do not overlap (in terms of file names = books).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If it is not implemented in git - is there a workaround to achieve this?

As explained in [your thread](https://public-inbox.org/git/CA+X_a+xu3WqJH-SRh2e733Z4izARRqjWjoVEaby=0iQ+T1rfGg@mail.gmail.com/T/#u) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason](https://github.com/avar)

> To answer the thought experiment don't conflate
> submodules with this, instead suppose that you have two branches A & B,
> which have:
>
> - `A`: `A.txt`
> - `B`: `B.txt`
>
> How will you create and maintain a third branch C which has the union of
> the two?
>
> The answer to that question will be the same as with the submodule case,
> i.e. you'd need to have some third branch that you maintain (e.g. with a
> push hook?) that would be a merge of the two, and ensure that you don't
> have path conflicts there.
>
> Then if you wanted to use such a branch as a submodule you'd grab that
> down like you would any other branch

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is just "no": no, there's no such thing as a mixed submodule in Git, and there's no workaround either.

#### Longer

The root of the problem here is that there's a grouping that cannot be reshuffled:<sup>1</sup>

- Git has a *current commit*, as found via the special name `HEAD`.
- Git has an *index* or *staging area* (two terms for the same thing<sup>2</sup>).
- Git has a *working tree*, which contains ordinary everyday files: that's where you do your work.

The reason for this is straightforward: *committed* files—files stored in commits—literally *can't* be changed, and are in a format that only Git itself can read.<sup>3</sup>  Git does this for multiple reasons, with the primary one being the *de-duplication* of files whose content is unchanged.  Hence, even though every Git commit stores every file, a new commit that only changes one file adds at most one file to the storage system.  (It may add *no* files, if it changes the file *back:* all duplicate files are shared with some earlier commit, and since we just said that only one file *changed*, all but one file is necessarily shared.  But if that one file now matches a file in *any* earlier commit—such as a commit made last week or last year—Git will share the storage from that earlier file.

Thus, the committed files work like permanent archives:<sup>4</sup> they *save a snapshot*, and later, you can get that snapshot of files back.  To do that you must supply the correct hash ID *to* Git.  We won't concern ourselves too much with the way you get the hash ID, except to mention that Git's submodules work by storing hash IDs.  But the archive is literally that: an *archive*, not a usable set of files.  So, having located an old archive of files, you then have Git "unpack" the archive itself, into a usable version of the files.

The usable version of the files is the working tree or work-tree.  Being a [*tree*](https://eecs.wsu.edu/%7Ecs207/hierarchy.htm), this working tree has a top level—a starting point folder or directory—that may contain sub-folders.  Each sub-folder is another tree and as such, it *could be* another Git working tree.  But usually—and always, initially—it isn't.

If a subfolder *isn't* another Git working tree, that subfolder is part of *this* tree.  So `sub/file1`, `sub/file2`, `sub/sub2/file`, and so on must all be part of *this* repository's commit as extracted from the *current commit* in *this repository*, by *this* `git checkout` or `git switch` operation.

Git keeps track of all of this through its *index* or *staging area*.  Unlike many more-traditional version control systems, Git doesn't *just* extract the commit into the working tree: instead, it effectively *copies* the commit to its index / staging-area as well.  Because the index holds the de-duplicated file format, and all the files are duplicates, this doesn't really take much space at all.<sup>5</sup>

When you run `git add` on any given working tree file, Git reads the working tree copy, compresses it into a freezable format object, checks to see if that's a duplicate, and then either uses the duplicate or uses the new thing it made in order to do the checking.  If that's a *new file*—a name that wasn't in your working tree before—it is also a new name *in the index*, and if that's an old file—a name that was there before—that kicks the previous duplicate out of the index.  In either case, the index is ready to commit, both before `git add`, and after `git add`.<sup>6</sup>

Overall it's an elegant solution: a file in your working tree is *tracked* if and only if it exists in this index, and `git commit` simply writes a new commit from the files that are already there in the index.  At the initial `git checkout` or `git switch` time, *all three copies* of each file—frozen committed `HEAD` copy, frozen-format-but-not-actually-frozen index copy, and usable working tree copy—all match.  You modify the working tree copy however you like, and now two copies match: `HEAD` and index.  You `git add` the modified working tree and now a *different two copies* match: index and working-tree.  When you're done modifying the *index*, you run `git commit`, and Git makes a *new commit;* the new commit becomes the `HEAD`, and now `HEAD` and index match.  If you `git add`-ed *everything* from your working tree, all three copies of everything match.  If you deliberately skipped some `git add`s, you're now free to add those and make *another* commit.  And, if you don't want to add *all* the changes you made to some file, you can use `git add -p`, or otherwise "patch" the index copy of some file, which you can then use to make a new commit.

But when we add submodules to the mix, everything gets tricky.

---

<sup>1</sup>You can—since Git 2.5—run `git worktree add` to add a *new* group of (HEAD, index, working-tree), but the working tree you add must be in a different location in the file system.  You are also required to use a different branch name, or detached-HEAD mode, in the added working tree; this is for reasons we won't get into here.

<sup>2</sup>There's a third term, *cache*, that is rarely used these days, but still shows up in command-line flags: for instance `git rm --cached` refers to removing a file from the index / staging-area, without removing it from the working tree.  Some commands, such as `git diff`, take *either* `--staged` *or* `--cached`, and some commands, such as `git rm`, still only allow the primeval-Git "cache" word here.  This might be fixed someday so that you can `git rm --staged`, but it's still the state as of Git 2.37.

<sup>3</sup>Git's internal *objects* can be stored as either "loose objects" or "packed objects".  Loose objects are merely zlib-compressed, so a lot of programs these days would theoretically be able to read these files, but packed objects are much more complicated; very few programs would know how to read one object out of a packed-objects file.

<sup>4</sup>No part of any commit can ever be changed, so the files *in* a commit are as permanent as the commit itself.  A commit can, however, become "dead" in a way.  The technical term for this is *unreachable*.  Some—not all!—Git implementations eventually "garbage collect" these unreachable commits and hence literally discard them entirely; if and when that happens, that particular archive is gone.  The general rule here, which is now weaker than it was in primeval Git, is that if you can *look up the commit hash ID at all*, you can get all of its files back.  If you can't look up the commit hash ID, you can't get the files from this repository: try another clone.

<sup>5</sup>Technically, the index holds a *blob hash ID* for each file, along with a file name and mode and a whole bunch of cache data.  There's also a *staging slot number* for each such file, for use during merge conflicts.  This is slightly different from commits, which use *tree objects* to store file names and lack the cache data and staging slot.  It comes to very roughly 100 bytes or so per file (depending on file name length) to store the index entries.  Of course, once you've changed a file and `git add`-ed it, Git has to store the new blob object somewhere, if that's not a duplicate.  (Git does not store this directly in the index.  Instead, it goes into the objects database as usual.  But that's just an implementation detail.)

<sup>6</sup>The one exception to this rule occurs when the index contains *nonzero staging slot entries*, which represent unmerged files.  When this is the case, `git commit` fails with an error saying that you have unmerged files.  Using `git add` tells Git to kick out the nonzero stage entries and put in a stage-zero entry, thereby resolving the unmerged state for that file.

---

#### Enter submodules, exit elegance

Given that the <`HEAD`, index, working-tree> triple represents frozen, semi-frozen, and liquid files for *one commit* from *one repository*, how do we mix in a *second* commit from a *second repository?*  Git's current answer to this is to use submodules.

A submodule, in Git, is implemented as several things that must match up.  Note that each submodule is a submodule *within* what Git calls a *superproject*, here.

- There is a file named `.gitmodules` that goes at the root of the working tree of the *superproject*.  This file contains instructions that Git can use to run `git clone`.  That's basically all it's for!
- There is, in *each commit in the superproject*, an entity that Git calls a *gitlink*.  This entity supplies two things: the path name at which the submodule is to have some commit checked out, and a raw hash ID of the commit *in* the submodule repository.<sup>7</sup>

To make this work, Git will:

- clone the submodule, if that hasn't been done yet, using the instructions in the `.gitmodules` file;
- run `git checkout` or `git switch --detach` using a raw commit hash ID.

The `git checkout` / `git switch` *fills in* an index and working tree.  It sets the `HEAD` of the <`HEAD`, index, working-tree> triple to the raw commit hash ID, fills in the index, and fills in the working tree.  For all of this to work, that working tree *must* be an *entire working tree* for a Git repository.  This means it *must* be a folder, presumably a sub-folder *within* the working tree of the superproject for which this submodule is a submodule.

When all of these conditions are in place, submodules work.  The sub-folder within the working tree of the superproject isn't considered "part of" the superproject, because Git doesn't "track" directories at all: only *files*—and in this special submodule case, *gitlinks*—can go into an index / staging-area.

For your case, though, you want some set of files stored in the superproject to go into some files and sub-directories in the working tree.  Then you want some set of files stored in a submodule to go into the *same* files and directories, or for more than one submodule to go into a *single working tree*.  But Git has this rule: one index "tracks" one tree.  Files that exist in the tree, but not in the index, are "untracked files".  You want to have a situation in which some files in some tree are tracked in one index, and other files in that same tree are tracked in the other index.  Git can't do that: it would have to read both indices and *assign* files to one or the other.

---

<sup>7</sup>Note how these two things—a pathname and a hash ID—are the *same two things* that *any* index entry records for *any* file.  It's just that for regular files, those are the file's name, e.g., `path/to/file.ext`, and a *blob* hash ID.  For a submodule, those are the submodule's path, e.g., `module` or `sub/module`, and a *commit* hash ID.  A file entity in a staging slot has `mode 100644` or `mode 100755`, and a gitlink entity has `mode 160000`.

---

#### What you can do

Depending on what, if anything, you want to *do* with these submodules and superproject, you might not care about correctly indexing the "submodule files".  If that's the case, you can fake it.  In fact, there's probably no reason to use submodules at all at this point:

- Have your superproject in a Git repository as usual.
- Check out a superproject commit as usual.  You now have a working tree.
- In that working tree, create an empty directory `data/` or whatever, and create a `.git` sub-directory there if necessary or desired so that the superproject won't even *attempt* to look inside it, and/or use `.gitignore` in the superproject to avoid any such looking-inside.
- Now clone and check out the commits you like from the "submodules", which might now just be separate Git repositories.  Move or copy all the working tree files into the `data/` directory.

Note that you can, if you like, use the existing checked-out "submodule" working trees as templates to know how to re-assign the "superproject" files back to the submodules if and when such files are updated.  And you can eliminate the "superproject" entirely, and just have the two "submodules" (two independent Git repositories): instead of making a `data/` you just make the target directory where you're going to combine working trees.

It's up to you, as the programmer, to decide what to do about name collisions: what if the two "submodules" both have files with the *same name?*  It's up to you, as the programmer, to decide what to do about a name vacuum: what if you create, in the work area, a *new* file?  How will you decide which "submodule" this file should be copied back to, in order to make a new commit in that "submodule"?

These are the questions you'll need to answer, after which it's just a [Small Matter of Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_matter_of_programming) to write the tools you want.  They won't be *Git* tools—not exactly anyway—but because you decided how they work, they will do the job you want.  [Or rather, they will do the job you tell them to.](https://cse.buffalo.edu/%7Eburhans/S01/honors/tsld034.htm)

Comment: WOW!... Such a deep knowledge!... I'll have to reread it several times till I really understand it. As for name vacuum/collisions one, e.g. can specify one of the submodules as being default (=dominant) and `git add` will go there (if not specified explicitly, e.g. `git add my_file.txt my_second_submodule`). Existing file from the dominant submodule will "overwrite" the other one (or create a conflict)...

Comment: 1. do you see what I'm suggesting just as more general case of submodules? 2. can it be a useful case for broader public? 3. can git be rewritten to support such "mixed" submodules or it is impossible by design? 4. is it worth opening a feature request for git?

Comment: Anything can be *written*, but not everything is necessarily a good idea. :-) As for "opening a feature request": there's a Git mailing list, but there's no formal Git issue tracker. Consider poking around in the mailing list archives and/or joining the list (just google "git mailing list"). I have some vague ideas myself along these lines but haven't made key decisions as to how this would all work.